# How to change predefined section name?

Tags: sectioning, ieeetran

I have looked at many answers (and tried them) for this particular question but nothing has worked for me. I've tried with the titlesec package but it gave me an error, and afterwards I noticed that it is not supported for conference paper. I want to change the section name. I want it to be larger, to be bold and to be flushed left.
I used

```
\section*{\raggedright{\bf \large {1. Introduction}}}
```

because without the '*' it didn't work and I had to put number manually. I know this is a really bad way of doing things, so can someone tell me how to change it in the preambula? I am new in latex so I will appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large ABSTRACT\\}
\title{Example}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `titlesec` can't help you, you have to somehow reinvent the wheel:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}
  {1\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip minus 0.25\baselineskip}
  {1\baselineskip plus 0.25\baselineskip minus 0.25\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Example}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that the last parameter of `\@startsection` is relevant to your particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you want to do this? If you are planning to submit this to IEEE, you shouldn't be doing this.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large ABSTRACT\\}

\makeatletter
\ifCLASSOPTIONconference%
% IEEE wants section heading spacing to decrease for conference mode
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{1.5ex plus 1.5ex minus 0.5ex}%
{0.7ex plus 1ex minus 0ex}{\normalfont\bfseries\large\raggedright\scshape}}%
\else % for journals
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{3.0ex plus 1.5ex minus 1.5ex}% V1.6 3.0ex from 3.5ex
{0.7ex plus 1ex minus 0ex}{\normalfont\bfseries\large\raggedright\scshape}}%
\fi
\makeatother

\title{Example}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}


\end{document}
```

[image]